# How to integrate FuelPHP with Behat?

Tags: integration, fuelphp, behat

I'm looking for a way to integrate my FuelPHP installation with behat. I have already a /features/ folder and the files required for Behat to work in my FuelPHP directory and I'm able to "play around" with some really basic stuff.

What I'm looking for is a way to get the FuelPHP core functions and classes to work with Behat.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: This might help: http://blog.phpdeveloper.org/?p=456

Comment: I have seen that before asking the question. It didn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got so far: I found that you can essentially reuse the `bootstrap_phpunit.php` file that comes with FuelPHP with Behat as well.

I created a directory named `fuel/app/tests` and ran `behat --init` in it (which created the basic `FeatureContext.php file`). I then created a file at `fuel/app/tests/features/bootstrap/Bootstrap.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['doc_root'] = '../..';
$_SERVER['app_path'] = 'fuel/app';
$_SERVER['core_path'] = 'fuel/core';
$_SERVER['package_path'] = 'fuel/packages';

require_once $_SERVER['doc_root'] . '/core/bootstrap_phpunit.php';
```

Once I did this, I seemed to be able to load FuelPHP classes from within the Behat context. I haven't spent too much time on it though, and haven't tested things like unit testing controllers. I've got all my business logic in a separate class to allow easier unit testing of it.